# Error in Mongodb replication on aws

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, replication, database

I am trying to do replication in Mongodb on aws.
I have created two ubuntu instances and ssh into them and initiated replication.
However when i am trying to add the second node using rs.add(), it gives the following error-

"
Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded:"

I am following this link to do this 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

This link suggests that i have to create three instances first, however i have just created 2 instances. Pls tell me if that is the reason for the error?

Comment: looks like its not able to reach the other member. To your query, its not mandatory to have 3 member replica set. You can have with two also.

Comment: can you telnet from one instance to the other one? `telnet mongo0.yourdomain.com 27017` — you'll probably need to configure your security groups accordingly